# Are parents also maya?

Tags: maya, parents

I love my parents more than anything in this world. Some days back my father was seriously ill and it seemed that my whole world was shattered. Then this question aroused in my mind,

Dose affection towards parents is Maya or worldly affection?

In Hinduism parents are God. So how affection towards God be Maya? Is it divine affection?

Comment: How does woman or wife create maya? How is she maya?

Comment: You have not understood Maya properly. One can know world as Maya **only after realization** in Advaita. One can't simply stay without eating as everything is Maya.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Beginners in Spiritual practices avoid women or try to develop Vairagya  by considering women as Maya. (or) it could be the case OP trying to understand Advaita.

Comment: The question is not clear to me.

Comment: @TheDestroyer  The reason I asked the Q is to understand what the OP understands of maya. Their statement implies that they understand and accept maya in a woman. If there is true understanding of maya, it can be extended to their Q related to parents also and answered appropriately. Teaching advaita is not appropriate if the understanding is not mature.

Comment: Are you trying to say that attachment to parents/family is a form of entanglement in Maya?

Comment: Please do the required edit if needed. I wanted to ask that whether affection and love towards parents( we consider them as God also) are Maya i.e. worldly affection? Or is it divine affection?

Comment: @SantanuDebnath It is not maya. It is divine affection.

Answer (score 1):

See first of all you will have to understand what is Maya n what is not... In case of human being
Leaving ones soul everything is Maya when a soul is born in this world by taking birth in a soul carrying device which is ones body or sharir . So any one born on this earth have to leave or die at one time but the body or sharir die and not the soul cause soul or atma is Amar ...
But the body which is made up of 5 elements that is jal(water), Agni(fire), vayu(air), bhoomi(earth), and Akash (space ) have to die one day cause it is not Amar and have to go back in its elemental form after it ceases it's functions ...
So soul takes a rebirth in a new body n have a new different life in that body.

So anything leaving soul which the new body have after birth is all Maya...
N the Maya is all that thing which makes one's soul  attached to it in form of love or lust or care or any kind of bondage through the means of its body..

So yaa ofcourse one's parents too are a kind of Maya .. 
It's all Maya leaving self soul ..
That's why Shri Krishna had considered each n every attachment to the worldly thing as a Maya . N so he was never attached to any kind of emotional bondage to any thing in his life . Neither parents nor wife . N hence only ,he could follow his aim-mission to clean whole samaj or society of devil n evil.
If he had  emotionally attached to any Maya or attracted to any Maya then he would not be able to perform his duties his aim of taking birth of cleaning society of evils..
But for a common man in this world this is not possible as a common man is not with that self controlled emotional power... And also there is not such any restrictions of detaching from all Maya for a human  .
Cause a common man can't do that n this is d difference between God n great sages n saints  and tapasvis from a common man .
So for a common man , one can only do one thing that is not getting attached too much to any thing either wife or sexual lust or , ones family or children or any materialistic thing  or ones God like parents ...
Instead one must do or carry n fulfill his/her duties to the respected person that is study as a child for his parents ,care n wellbeing of his /her parents in his/her adulthood ,love n loyalty to his family n his duties for a good family life n then care n upliftment of his children ,etc 
So one must do All the different duties in ones life according to time . N not get attached too much to any one ...
Cause if that thing will leave you then you will get in world of sadness , sorrow n difficulties in living a life n carrying your duty towards your life..
N this is what is Maya .. which when gets apart from you , gives a difficulty in case of materialistic things of joyor pleasure or any kind of ease in Ur life; gives you sadness sorrow hardship in living life in case of loved ones , parents etc..
So be less attached as less as possible n live a life of carrying out Ur duties toward Ur life n your birth ...
N the one who r completely gets detached in life with all this things are the ones who we preach  i.e. sages , saadhus, acharya's , etc .
So by living a normal common life too ucan be detached from the worldly Maya without necessarily  following the path of these tapasvis, saadhus..

Comment: Welcome. You can try adding some references in your answer.

Comment: Arya Yes ofcourse attachment to family n parents is also an entanglement in Maya .. attachment to any relation or materialistic thing which we get after birth is all Maya n so we must not be attached to it very much that those relationship only become the reason behind our weakness n we can't do our duty or our aim in life ...

Comment: Actually @Ash.R . I agree with your last comment. My question start from them. Hinduism also say that parents are like god to us. Then how affection towards god could be Maya?